# Separate locators in .json file - Cypres

Tags: testing, cypress

Is it possible to separate locators in .json file while working with Cypress?
I can't seem to find anything about this online, but it seems like something that should be possible.

I separated my locator in a .json file but I have problems with calling them in my tests.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't heard of anyone doing this and I wouldn't recommend it - storing selectors in the tests is the best method IMO.  However if you're set on it you could store them in a file in the `fixtures` directory, then access them with `cy.fixture()`.  Something like this:

```
cy.fixture('selectors.json').then(selectors => {
  cy.get(selectors.mySelector).click()
})
```

Comment: I see some merit in having selectors in a fixture, for example if running the same tests on different pages and the selectors have a content-based component.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to load the selectors in a `before()`

```js
let selectors;
before(function(){
  cy.fixture('selectors').then(s => selectors = s)
})

it('...', () => {
  cy.get(selectors.mySelector).click()
})
```